# Snowflake | Insert overwrite fails with Expression type does not match column data type, expecting TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9) but got FLOAT for column

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Trying to insert overwrite data from one table with x+y columns into table with x+z columns and getting error
`SQL compilation error: Expression type does not match column data type, expecting TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9) but got FLOAT for column DATEMODIFIED`.
In this case data type for DATEMODIFIED on both tables is `TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9)`.
Query goes like below

```sql
insert overwrite into tgt_table
select x1,x2,x3, DATEMODIFIED,  null as z1, null as z2 from 
(select x1,x2,x3, DATEMODIFIED from src_table)
```

- Column description for source table
  [image: source table description]
- Column description of target table
  [image]

**Note:**

- Datemodified is null in source table and even replacing DateModified with
  `COALESCE(DateModified, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP::TIMESTAMP_NTZ) as DateModified` doesn't solve the problem.
- Rewriting the query like below doesn't solve the problem

```sql
insert overwrite into tgt_table
select x1,x2,x3, DATEMODIFIED::TIMESTAMP_NTZ  as DateModified,  null as z1, null as z2 from 
(select x1,x2,x3, DATEMODIFIED::TIMESTAMP_NTZ  as DateModified from src_table)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the order of the columns in the target table is different.
Try to define target columns in your command like this:

```sql
insert overwrite into tgt_table (x1,x2,x3, DATEMODIFIED, z1, z2)
select x1,x2,x3, DATEMODIFIED,  null as z1, null as z2 from 
(select x1,x2,x3, DATEMODIFIED from src_table)
```

Reference: [INSERT target_col_name](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/insert.html#optional-parameters)

Comment: it was exactly the same issue.